# Pytest on relative paths

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, relative-path

How to test the relative path using pytest

```
base_path = Path(__file__).parent
file_path = (base_path / "test.json").resolve()
logger.info(file_path)
f1 = open(file_path)
json_load = json.load(f1)
logger.info(json_load)
return json_load
```

need to validate this using pytest. since i am very new to pytest do provide some insights

Comment: what are you trying to test, that the file exists in the path?

Comment: yes @gold_cy ..